# Problems installing the AMD Catalyst Radeon driver in Debian Wheezy on my HP Notebook

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, debian-wheezy

I tried to install AMD catalyst graphics driver for my HP Notebook with specifications as follows:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series
```

I already tried installing with [instructions from this page](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) but got error like this:

```
Loading new fglrx-12-6+point DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.7-trunk-686-pae
Building initial module for 3.7-trunk-686-pae<br>
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7-trunk-686-pae (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/12-6+point/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing fglrx-modules-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-modules-dkms
```

After that I installed—with proper instructions from forums—`amd-catalyst-13.10-beta2-linux-x86.x86_64.zip` which did not work for me.

Then I installed `amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip` but this time the installer says I’ve successfully completed installation and gave me a prompt to reboot the system and I did.

When it booted up the system, it jst displays a black screen with sort of underline cursor and I’m not able to do anything.

I didn’t change or configure `xorg.conf` after the installation.